# Some common Fontawesome icons are not being displayed on Joomla menu

Tags: joomla, menu, icons

I'm trying to save space on my main menu so that it fits onto the mobile screen. However, I found that some very common icons such as sign in, sign out and toolbox are not being displayed. The on-hover tooltip displays though and the link as such does work. It's just that the icons are not shown, even though several others are.

Comment: I found the answer. The reason is that Joomla is based on boostrap 3 and thus only works with fontawesome icons version 4. The icons I was trying to use that did not work were from the newer version 5.

https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/

Comment: Every page on StackOverflow should progress to some type of system-recognized resolution.  1. Accepted Answer 2. Question Closure or 3. Page Deletion.  If you are going to keep this question alive, please post your solution as an answer and accept it.  If you not, you are welcome to remove your question.